# Expected Declaration when Checking iOS Version in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add iOS version checking on my code, however, I always got this error
[image]

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
   var tagSession: NFCTagReaderSession!
} else {
}
```

I can't use @available(iOS 13.0, *) because I still want to use this scene for below iOS 13.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use a condition on an instance property declaration.

Comment: @matt I need it to declare NFC however I don't want a whole page only available in ios 13+. do you have suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Have you tried [@available](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-available-to-check-for-api-availability)?